# Discord bot not running until I close Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I'm trying my hand at making a simple discord bot and have a weird issue. Whenever I run my code nothing happens, I can send the Ping command as many times as I like but nothing will happen in the discord until I close Spyder completely (not manually ending the script) then suddenly all the messages come through. Another odd issue I have is that I can't get it to print anything into while its running.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Heres my code for reference:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Bot ready')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round (client.latency * 1000)} ms')

client.run('BOT TOKEN')
```

Edit: tried running it from cmd, the code will run but no messages will send at all even if end the script or close out

Comment: Can you try running the script normally, outside of spyder?

Comment: Honestly never run code outside of spyder but I'll give it a go